# Let $f:[0,1]\to f([0,1])$ be a mapping such that $f(t)=(1-t)a+tb$, where $a,b\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $a\neq b$. Show that $f$ is a homeomorphism.

Tags: general-topology

> Let $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}^n$ be a mapping such that $f(t)=(1-t)a+tb$, where $a,b\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $a\neq b$.
> Show that $f:[0,1]\to f([0,1])$ is a homeomorphism.

My solution is here:

> Let $a=(a_1,\dots,a_n)$.
> Let $b=(b_1,\dots,b_n)$.
> Then, $f(t)=(f_1(t),\dots,f_n(t))=((1-t)a_1+tb_1,\dots,(1-t)a_n+tb_n)=(t(b_1-
> a_1)+a_1,\dots,t(b_n-a_n)+a_n)$.
> $f_i:[0,1]\to f_i([0,1])$ is bijective and continuous since $f_i$ is a linear function.
> $f^{-1}_i$ is also continuous since $f^{-1}_i$ is also a linear function.
> $f$ is bijective and continuous since each $f_i$ is bijective and continuous.
> $f$ is an open mapping since each $f_i$ is an open mapping.
> So, $f$ is a homeomorphism.

Is my solution ok?
If my solution is not ok, please tell me a correct solution.
If my solution is ok, then please tell me the standard solution for this problem.

Comment: Each $f_i$ is linear (in the polynomial sense, rather than the linear map sense), which implies continuity. Restricting the map to $f_i([0, 1])$ makes it surjective. However, beware that this does not quite imply injectivity! If the map is constant, then it will be linear but not injective. And, what's worse, some of these maps could be constant, even taking into account $a \neq b$. That's something you should address in the proof.

Comment: @TheoBendit Thank you very much for your correction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there, I will emphasize the part that you omit from injectivity.

Recall that a map $f: X\to Y$ is a homeomorphim iff (a) $f$ is bijective,  (b) $f$ is continuous and (c) $f^{-1}$ is continuous.

(a) $f$ is bijective iff is injective and onto. Since $f\colon [0,1]\to f([0,1])$ so $f$ is surjective. In order to show injectivity we show that
$$\forall t_1, t_2\in [0,1]\colon \quad f(t_1)=f(t_2)\implies t_2=t_1.$$
Indeed,
$$f(t_1)=f(t_2)$$ $$(1-t_1)a+t_1 b=(1-t_2)a+t_2 b,\quad a\not=b$$
$$(1-t_1-1+t_2)a+(t_1-t_2)b=0$$
$$(t_2 - t_1)a-(t_2 - t_1)b=0$$
$$(t_2 -t_1)(a-b)=0$$
Since $a\not=b$, then the product is zero iff $t_2 -t_1=0$, that is, when $t_2=t_1$. Hence $f$ is injective.

Thus, $f$ is bijective.

For (b) and (c) the continuity of $f$ and $f^{-1}$ is follows since each component of the function is linear $t\mapsto (1-t)a+tb$.

Therefore, $f$ is a homeomorphim.

Comment: A. P., Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: @tchappyha: I hope my answer is useful for you, good luck in your studies!